# jQuery - How to remove element in the next li based on src

Tags: jquery

I'd like to remove the hyperlikned `target.jpg` image in the next `li` when the `remove target image` is clicked. Here is the html:

```
<li id="remover">
    remove target image
</li>

<li>
    <a hre="/path1"> <img src="/path/to/img1.jpg" >  </a>
    <a hre="/path2"> <img src="/path/to/target.jpg" >  </a>
    <a hre="/path3"> <img src="/path/to/img3.jpg" >  </a>                      
<li>
```

I'm wondering how can I achieve this?

UPDATE: please notice I want to remove only THE NEXT image (including it's containing hyperlink), not all images on the page with that `src`.

So the result should be:

```
<li id="remover">
    remove target image
</li>
<a href="/path1"> <img src="/path/to/img1.jpg">  </a>
<a href="/path3"> <img src="/path/to/img3.jpg">  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#remover').click(function () {
            $(this).next('li').find("img[src='/path/to/target.jpg']").parent('a').remove();
});
```

when you remove the a the img inside is removed as well

Comment: Does this guarantee that only the NEXT image with that src is removed?

Comment: @Babr Nope, it does not. If there are multiple images of the same source that exist, I suggest updating your answer to better reflect the context.

Comment: something like that?

Comment: @b3nc1, I need to remove the `a` around the target image too. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work for me. What should I put instead of ` $(this)` when the remove is trigered inside a `success: function` ?

Comment: use $('#remover')

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the first element where src is the target, you should find it, get the parent `<a>` and remove the children:

```
$(document).on('click, '#remover', function() {
  $("img[src=/path/to/target.jpg]").first().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Well, I want to remove the hyperlink to, that is `<a hre="/path2"> <img src="/path/to/target.jpg" >  </a>` need to be removed.